# range.deleteContents() is unexpectedly removing whitespace before the range itself

Tags: javascript, html, dom

if the text is `sure :f`, `range.deleteContents()` suppose to delete `:f`, but, it's deleting  `:f`. It looks like space before `:` character is also getting removed.
How to retain the space before `:`? Alternatively, Is there any other way to remove text which is more reliable?

```js
const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(selection.focusNode, 5); // start of :
  range.setEnd(selection.focusNode, 7);
  range.deleteContents(); //deletes ` :f`
```

It doesn't matter if I set `range.setStart(selection.focusNode, 4)` or `range.setStart(selection.focusNode, 5)`.. space is getting removed.

Here's the fiddle to play around: https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/o2c9f5gw/

Comment: Oh that's a bad bug in Chrome (and Safari). It even thinks it made the correct thing: https://jsfiddle.net/m7q3tcw0/

Comment: Ok, so this is actually not related to the call to `deleteContents`, it's simply that the CSS `white-space: normal` will remove any ending white space in an element. Forcing `white-space: pre`, we get the expected result: https://jsfiddle.net/hmw91ufy/ I doubt this is specced anywhere, but I guess you could make a point at https://crbug.com/ at least for `contenteditable` elements.

Comment: yeah seems like it's a bug so I moved to `document.execCommand('delete')`